# What's the difference between these two while loops?

Tags: c++

What's the difference between these two while loops? I don't understand what they do.

First:

```
while(condition) ;
```

Second:

```
while(condition){ };
```

Comment: One has an extra statement.

Comment: Did you put each in a `main()`, compile and run, just to *see what happens before asking here* ??

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference, both `while` loops enclose an empty statement.

The practical result is an infinite loop which will never end, unless there's another thread or some side effect that changes `condition`.

Answer (score 0):

first code is **optional short form** for second code, which is suitable when you need to do only 1 operation in loop, like:

```
while (condition is true)
    condition=dosomething();
```

you can safely re-write this like:

```
while (condition is true)
{
    condition=dosomething();
}
```

this will be absolutely the same

but if you need several statements in loop, you need to "group" them somehow, so compiler will know what parts of code should be "looped", this is done via `{` and `}`

so, for several statements you cannot use short form, you can only do:

```
while (condition is true)
{
    condition=dosomething();
    dosomething2();
    dosomething3();
}
```

for multi-threading programming we can have next situation:

1. Thread1: set condition to true
2. Thread1: create new thread2 and run it
3. Thread1: now need to wait until thread2 is finished, thread2 will set condition to false when it done to notify 1st one

so, for such situations sometimes you can use infinite loop like

`while (condition) ;` or `while (condition) { };` - which are the same as we see above

this mean - do single operation, but operation is not provided, this means just wait until other thread will set this variable to false

NOTE: such infinity loops usually is bad practice and it is better to avoid them and use only when you're sure that this has sense

Answer (score 0):

The loops themselves are the same, but the second one is followed by the null statement, so if this code was oart of a larger control structure they could parse differently: for example, if they were part of a nested 'if' statement the first one could be followed by 'else', but the second could not.